# Align content of HubSection to Bottom

Tags: xaml

I have a HubSection with StackPanel inside.  i would like to move StackPanel to the Bottom of Hub Section.

Here is my XAML:

```
<HubSection Width="783">
   <DataTemplate>
     <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
        <TextBlock ...
     </StackPanel>
```

But I have StackPanel on the Top of the HubSection.  How can I fix it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to place your StackPanel inside another container that will fill the entire HubSection, leaving your StackPanel able to align to the bottom of that container:

```
<HubSection Width="783" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch">
   <DataTemplate>
     <Grid>
        <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
           <TextBlock ...
        </StackPanel>
     </Grid>
```

Comment: My apologies, I missed out the VerticalContentAlignment property. Please give this another go.